# Where do i go to modify the 500 error page for Magento?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, magento

I am making a site live for a client and i want to debadge all instances of Magento on the front end, but I can seem to find where modify the 500 error template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the template you're looking for is `/errors/default/report.phtml` (previously `/report/skin/default/index.phtml`).  You might also be interested in [this article](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-how-to-custom-error-page-design/) on specifying a different template if you don't want to modify the standard template.

Comment: +1 for linking to an article about further customisation of error reporting.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but the link is unfortunately dead :(

Answer (score 1):

You can specify error pages via your .htaccess file.  Just enter this code in your htaccess file specifying what page you want them to see:
`ErrorDocument 500 /error-docs/500.html`

Obviously you can change the number to change any error page.